# I want to mock getRowNode() to do some mock unit test on OnCellValueChanged

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

this.api.getRowNode(id!); and i need to pass it from test case ?

I am getting error cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'getRowNode')

Even i am spying on rowNode

Comment: please share your component and test code so we can help

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.